# How to obsolete existing method in .Net framework?

Tags: c#

My project is global used solution, so I should consider every time for cultural difference.

For instance, I'd like to mark some existing method should not be used in my project.

```
//warning have to be shown when build or any other way
DateTime temp1 = DateTime.Parse("190101");

//only this code is accepted
bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact("190101", "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime temp2)
```

What I want is, I'd like to make some method not to use (or alarming). (not my method, .NET existing method)

Is there any way to achieve that I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest option for this is probably to [write a Roslyn analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019). That can analyze your source code, warn you about the methods you don't want to allow, and even suggest a fix. Writing an analyzer isn't a trivial matter, but it's not *too* bad, at least for simple cases - and I believe your case *is* reasonably simple.

It's able to react to much more than just "which methods you're allowed to use" too - you might want to validate that `TryParseExact` is always called with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, for example. Although you might well be better off creating your own utility class with "parse date", "parse date/time" methods etc, and make your analyzer validate that you're not calling `DateTime.Parse/ParseExact/TryParse/TryParseExact` anywhere except in that class.

Answer (score -2):

For that you need to add this decoration to the method
[Obsolete]

Comment: This is not possible for .NET Framework methods. Only for code you can change.

Comment: The question is asking about existing .NET methods. You can't apply `[Obsolete]` to those.